# Link to wrap around li with padding

Tags: html, css, list, css-selectors

I have an unordered list with a lot of list items. Some of the list items are links, some are not. I want to add padding to the list items so the appearance is consistent regardless of whether it is a link or not, i.e. I do not want to add padding to the anchor, but to the list and for the anchor to wrap around the link AND padding.

Despite using `display:block` on hover the background color is only around the text inside the link. It ignores the padding. Is there a way to get the link to include the padding (without putting padding on the link)?

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 5em;
  padding: 0 2em;
}
a:link {
  display: block;
}
a:visited {
  display: block;
}
a:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
a:active {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="1.html">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="2.html">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li><a href="5.html">Item 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in a fiddle and this is what I got https://jsfiddle.net/Lkughrna/ That doesn't really give us much info on what the problem is. Please consider creating a working fiddle for us.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio see a semi-colon missing after `line-height: 5em`... https://jsfiddle.net/jagwfb11/ (the `hover` color matches the jsfiddle background!)

Comment: That's unlucky that the color exactly matches the JS Fiddle background!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hover` the `li` instead of the `a` to correct the `background-color` applied on `hover` by using:

```
li:hover a {
  display: block;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

instead of:

```
a:hover { 
  display:block; 
  background-color:rgb(245,245,245);
}
```

See demo below:

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 5em;
  padding: 0 2em;
}
a:link {
  display: block;
}
a:visited {
  display: block;
}
li:hover a {
  display: block;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
a:active {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="1.html">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="2.html">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li><a href="5.html">Item 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. I don't understand it, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, my comments should explain everything but feel free to ask.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="1.html">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li><a href="5.html">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>  

ul{
    list-style-type: none;  /* Feel free to remove this, just easier without bullets */
}

ul li {
    float: left;    
    line-height: 5em;       /* Should be the same as height */
    padding: 0 2em;
    position: relative;     /* Make sure a & a:before can stay contained */
    height: 5em;            /* Should be same as line-height */
    white-space: nowrap;    /* Ensure that your items don't wrap and mess up width */
    z-index: -1;            /* So that a:before is able to trigger with :hover */
}

a{
    position: relative;     /* Make sure a:before can stay contained */
    display: block;         /* Ensures that a can expand to full size of container */
}

a:before{ 
    content: "";            /* Necessary for :before element to be created */
    position: absolute;     /* Vital - allows positioning */
    top: 0; 
    right: -2em;        /* Minus same padding as li has */
    bottom: 0;
    left: -2em;         /* Minus same padding as li has */
    z-index: -1;            /* Makes sure :before doesn't go above anchor text */
}

a:hover:before,
a:active:before { 
    background-color:rgb(245,245,245); 
}
```

Comment: Where are your comments explaining anything?

Comment: Sorry when I posted it threw out half of my code. Comments are next to the css in the code.